# Recursive list of lists in XSL

Tags: xslt, recursion

I have a recursive nodes that I'm trying to set up for jquery-checktree.  The nodes look like

```
foo/bar/ID
       /NAME
       /CHECKED
       bar/ID
          /NAME
          /CHECKED
   /bar/ID
       /NAME
   /bar/ID
       /NAME
       /bar/ID
           /NAME
           /CHECKED
           /bar/ID
               /NAME
               /CHECKED
```

Where any bar may or may not have one or more bar nodes below it, but any bar will have ID and NAME and might have a CHECKED.

and I want to turn that into

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="..." value="..." checked="checked"></input>
      <label for="...">...</label>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="..." value="..." checked="checked"></input>
          <label for="...">...</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
  <li>....</li>
</ul>
```

I can get the first level by doing:

```
    <ul class="tree">
    <xsl:for-each select="/foo/bar/">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="{ID}" value="{ID}">
            <xsl:if test="CHECKED = 'Y'"><xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            </input><label for="{ID}"><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></label>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
```

But I don't know how to recurse down to the embedded "bar" within the "bar", down to however many levels there might be.

Comment: @Paul: Resist the urge to use `<xsl:for-each>`. Most of the time it stands in the way of an elegant solution. Try to get things done with `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead, not only does this reduce the nesting complexity of your stylesheet, it also enables you to produce a content-driven transformation, as opposed to an iterative/imperative approach.

Comment: @Tomalak: I mostly agree - if you can, template matching delivers the clearest design. But I find I can't always use match in a straightforward way to solve my own problems. But in this case, I agree completely, match is better than for-each + call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
<xsl:template match="bar">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="{ID}" value="{ID}">
            <xsl:if test="CHECKED = 'Y'">
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </input>
        <label for="{ID}"><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></label>
        <!-- 

            If we have bar children, make a list and recurse

        -->
        <xsl:if test="bar">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

This relies on the "automatic" template matching. To ensure the matching takes place, you could either put a `<xsl:apply-templates/>` inside the `<xsl:for-each>` loop of your original code, however, you can even improve it all and replace that original code with this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/foo">
   <ul class="tree">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="bar"/>
   </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want more control, you can also use `<xsl:for-each select="bar">` and call a named template (`<xsl:template name="some-name">...` and `<xsl:call-template>`) inside the loop. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#named-templates

Comment: It doesn't seem to be finding the first "bar".

Comment: Also, how do I get the first `<ul></ul>`?

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: what you see here is just part of a stylesheet, illustrating only the recursion. I will amend my answer to ensure matching of the entire structure.

Comment: Thanks - I'm really an xsl newbie and I need all the help I can get.

Comment: Paul: xslt is hard and simple at the same time...it's hard to explain. Don't let it get you down, it may take some time to grok it, but once you do, it can make some terribly complicated things extremely simple.  Unfortunately it makes some other things that should be simple terribly complicated, but that's another story :)

Comment: My "xsl:for-each" was in a different "xsl:template", so I had to put a `<xsl:apply-templates select="/foo">` in place of the for-each and put the other templates outside, but that appears to have done what I want.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example (proof of concept, actually) for a completely input-driven, push-style solution (template matching only, no conditionals, no named templates):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
>

  <xsl:template match="*[bar]">
    <ul class="tree">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="bar" mode="li" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bar" mode="li">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="checkbox" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="(.)[bar]" />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="bar" mode="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{ID}" name="{NAME}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CHECKED" />
    </input>
    <label for="{ID}">
      <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
    </label>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CHECKED">
    <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this input XML (extrapolated from your question):

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <ID>nd1</ID>
    <NAME>Node 1</NAME>
    <CHECKED />
    <bar>
      <ID>nd2</ID>
      <NAME>Node 2</NAME>
      <CHECKED />
    </bar>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <ID>nd3</ID>
    <NAME>Node 3</NAME>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <ID>nd4</ID>
    <NAME>Node 4</NAME>
    <bar>
      <ID>nd5</ID>
      <NAME>Node 5</NAME>
      <CHECKED />
      <bar>
        <ID>nd6</ID>
        <NAME>Node 6</NAME>
        <CHECKED />
      </bar>
    </bar>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

It produces this output:

```
<ul class="tree">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nd1" name="Node 1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="nd1">Node 1</label>
    <ul class="tree">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nd2" name="Node 2" checked="checked" />
        <label for="nd2">Node 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nd3" name="Node 3" />
    <label for="nd3">Node 3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nd4" name="Node 4" />
    <label for="nd4">Node 4</label>
    <ul class="tree">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nd5" name="Node 5" checked="checked" />
        <label for="nd5">Node 5</label>
        <ul class="tree">
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="nd6" name="Node 6" checked="checked" />
            <label for="nd6">Node 6</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
    <ul class="tree">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar" name="wunderbar">
<!-- we want to match all bars, not only /foo/bars -->
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="{ID}" value="{ID}">
        <xsl:if test="CHECKED = 'Y'"><xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
        </input><label for="{ID}">
            <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
        </label>
        <!-- If there is some bar, the next template is applied -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar/bar">
<!-- Just adds <ul> around bar included in bar and calls the usual template -->
    <ul>
        <xsl:call-template name="wunderbar"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```